# Al cambiar el nombre del equipo integrarlo a un dominio mediante .ps1, cuando reinicio la PC, solo toma el cambio de dominio y no del nombre

Tags: powershell

Este es el script que utilizo

## Pedir al usuario nombre del equipo

$ComputerName = Read-Host "Nuevo Nombre"

## Pedir al usuario nombre del dominio

$Domain Name = Read-Host "Nombre del dominio"

## Renombrar el equipo

Rename-Computer -NewName $ComputerName -Force

## Unir equipo al dominio

Add-Computer -DomainName $DomainName -NewName $ComputerName